# Dict comprehension with numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have 4 NumPy arrays: a, b, c, d

I am running: `{i: i.shape for i in [a,b,c,d]}`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    {i:i.shape for i in [a,b,c,d]}
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
    {i:i.shape for i in [a,b,c,d]}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to make a numpy array as your dict key...you can't do that

Comment: I mean I want it to be "a": (10, 13), "b": (3,4,43) etc.

Comment: What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: @David a dict like you've produced in your answer that I have accepted!

Comment: Dictionary keys have to be immutable, unlike values which don't need to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code tries to make the numpy array as the key, rather than the variable name you are assigning the array to. Something like below would work

```
{i[1]: i[0].shape for i in [(a, "a"), (b, "b"), (c, "c") , (d, "d")]}
```

Comment: Or: `{name: locals()[name].shape for name in "abcd"}`

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a numpy array as a key. Try using something like:

```
{i:arr.shape for i,arr in enumerate([a,b,c,d])}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution (just to give you options, as other people have already posted good ones):

```
{name: arr.shape for arr,name in zip([a,b,c,d],'abcd')}
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re trying to use a numpy.ndarray as the key for your shape. This won’t work as the object isn’t hashable and you probably want to use something else as your key.

Comment: But how can I tell the dict to take "a", "b" ... as keys?